# Using parent constructor in a child class in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class "ChildClass" that extends the class "ParentClass". Rather than completely replace the constructor for the parent class, I want to call the parent class's constructor first, and then do some extra work.

I believe that by default the parent class's 0 arguments constructor is called. This isn't what I want. I need the constructor to be called with an argument. Is this possible?

I tried

```
this = (ChildClass) (new  ParentClass(someArgument));
```

but that doesn't work because you can't modify "this".

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can reference the parent's constructor with "super", from within a child's constructor.

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(int someArg) {
        super(someArg);
        // other stuff
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: The call to the parent's constructor with super() needs to be the FIRST call in your child constructor.

Answer (score 10):

To invoke a specific parent-class constructor, put `super(param1, param2, ...)` as the first statement in the child-class constructor body.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the super keyword.

```
public ChildClass(...) {
    super(...);
}
```